# Create a thread to send and wait for response (websockets)

Tags: java, websocket

Have a method to connect to socket and send the message and sleep for a sec to process the response.

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.ning.http.client.websocket.WebSocket;
import com.ning.http.client.websocket.WebSocketTextListener;
import com.ning.http.client.websocket.WebSocketUpgradeHandler;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class SocketClient implements WebSocketTextListener {

    private static org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketClient.class);
    private WebSocket websocket;
    private List<String> serverResponse = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> logFromResponse = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getAllLogs(String receiverId){
        logFromResponse = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jObj.put("deviceId", receiverId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.warn("JSON Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
        connectToSocket();
        if (websocket!=null)
            websocket.sendTextMessage(jObj.toString());

        responseFromServer();

        return logFromResponse;
    }

    public boolean clearForDevice(String receiverId){
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jObj.put("deviceId", receiverId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.warn("JSON Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

        connectToSocket();
        if (websocket!=null)
            websocket.sendTextMessage(jObj.toString());

        String res = responseFromServer();
        return (res!=null) && res.contains("Success");
    }

    private void connectToSocket() {
        AsyncHttpClient c = new AsyncHttpClient();

        AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder builder = c.prepareGet(createUri())
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, "Upgrade")
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.UPGRADE, "WebSocket");

        websocket = builder.execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder()
                .addWebSocketListener(this).build()).get(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
        log.debug("Opening WebSocket");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket) {
        log.debug("Closing WebSocket");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) { }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        serverResponse.add(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragment(String s, boolean b) {    }

    private String responseFromServer() {
        String response = null;
        sleep(100);
        if (!serverResponse.isEmpty()) {
            //format message and send response and add to logFromResponse
        }
        return response;
    }

    protected void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("Interrupted Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

but, I want to do it without the sleep() for 1 sec, Connecting to socket using AsyncHttpClient which is not Blocking io. I would like to create a thread which can send the message and wait for the response from the server? I did try to create a class by implementing runnable interface but no luck!
Any suggestions how to create synchronous call to websockets or Blocking IO.

**UPDATE:** Using synchronized blocks to wait and then notify once the message is received! Followed @Antoniossss comment

Comment: Can't you use synchronized client insteed of async one and send/receive in another thread?

Comment: Anyway, what is the `websocket`? what is in `responseFromServer()` what kind of API is that anyway, as it is not `javax.websocket` as tag would suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from Ning home page

```
    import com.ning.http.client.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;

    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.ning.com/").execute(); //here you will execute async request
    Response r = f.get(); // here you will block until respons is accessible;
```

So I guess that `AsyncHttpClient` is designed to be `Sync` if needed as this piece of code will block and wait for the response. When you invoke `get()` after some time, probably response will be accessible right away as the request has been finished in meantime.

Now run both parts, execution and response reding in new thread, or execute request in main thread, and wait for the response (the `get()` part) in background thread - voila

Comment: Where and how can I send the textMessage?